# Can iOS colors use custom values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, logos

If a custom color is defined by UIColor and a variable is used in the color (e.g. colorWithAlpha:balfa) the variable will not be used and instead the alpha will default to the goto value.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.app.me~prefs.plist"];

static CGFloat bart;

static void PrefLoad()
{
    bart = [dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] ? [[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] floatValue] : 0.42;
}

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:bart];
```

In this case the alpha value is automatically set to 0.42 (defined as a default) even when the user has changed the value of the slider to something higher or lower.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This question is unclear. What problem are you actually having? Are you saying that no matter, `[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"]` is always `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy no, no matter what, bartf is always 0.42 (at the end of the second line)

Comment: Which means that `[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"]` is always `nil`. Have you verified that `dict` is not `nil`? If so, does it contain a value for the key `@"bartf"`?

Comment: @rmaddy dict is defined and other prefs in the code work (bools) and bartf is inside the dict

Comment: Add this just before your attempt to set `bart`: `NSNumber *bartNum = dict[@"bartf"];`. Then log it. What do you get?

Comment: @rmaddy i get a warning: unused label: bart

Comment: I think you need to update your question with more code.

Comment: @rmaddy edited it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the code that sets the bartf value in the dictionary.

THIS:

> bart = [dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] ? [[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"]
>   floatValue] : 0.42;

explains why it never changes. **[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] *is always null***.

Make sure your code is updating that dictionary correctly. To debug add a:

> NSLog(@"%@", dict);

after where you create this dictionary, and make sure the value is there.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
NSNumber *bartNum = dict[@"bartf"];
NSLog(@"bartNum = %@", bartNum);

static CGFloat bart;

bart = [dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] ? [[dict objectForKey:@"bartf"] floatValue] : 0.42;

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:bart];
```

and post what do you have in debug window.

Comment: 17:29: bartNum = (null)

Comment: ok. So your dict does not contain object for @"bartf". So problem is not in the code you have posted but somewhere else.

Comment: You can use NSLog(@"dict = %@", dict); to check if dict is valid and what values does it contain.

Comment: The debug windows shows (null) but the other preferences I'm using (bools) are working fine.

Comment: So dict is not initialized. This is a root of problem. For bools preferences you probably have FALSE (NO, 0) values - so they work fine. If you will try to set them to TRUE I think you will find that bool preference storage also not work.

Comment: inside the prefs file I can see that the bools are stored properly in an "off" or "on" state

Comment: I believe plist is ok. But it does not mean that NSDictionary is loaded correctly. Are you sure that plist path is correct?